Renovate how to filter out image prefix containing registry URL when trying to match images in private Azure Container Registry
I use the integrated Renovate bot in Gitlab to scan my Gitlab repository on dependent image updates. The bot scans the images used in my docker-compose.yml and looks at my private Azure Container Registry (ACR) if there are any dependent image updates. Currently this fails, as the image name used in my docker-compose.yml is not the same as the image name in my ACR. Renovate states that it cannot find my package. How do I solve this?
I know I have to usepackageRules and customManagers, but don't really understand how my renovate.json should look like implementing this.
Current setup
docker-compose.yml:
services:
  prometheus:
    image: <ACR_URL>/<TEAM>/prometheus:0.0.1

ACR image name:
<TEAM>/prometheus
Renovate bot logging:
{
  "depName": "<ACR_URL>/<TEAM>/prometheus",
  "currentValue": "0.0.1",
  "replaceString": "<ACR_URL>/<TEAM>/prometheus:0.0.1",
  "autoReplaceStringTemplate": "{{depName}}{{#if newValue}}:{{newValue}}{{/if}}{{#if newDigest}}@{{newDigest}}{{/if}}",
  "datasource": "docker",
  "updates": [],
  "packageName": "<ACR_URL>/<TEAM>/prometheus",
  "versioning": "docker",
  "warnings": [
    {
     "topic": "<ACR_URL>/<TEAM>/prometheus",
     "message": "Failed to look up docker package <ACR_URL>/<TEAM>/prometheus"
    }
  ]
},

This is my current renovate.json:
{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "extends": [
    "config:base"
  ],
  "baseBranches": [
    "main"
  ],
   "hostRules": [
    {
      "matchHost": "$ACR_URL",
      "username": "$ACR_USER",
      "password": "$ACR_TOKEN"
    }
  ],
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "groupName": "all non-major dependencies",
      "groupSlug": "all-minor-patch",
      "matchPackagePatterns": [
        "*"
      ],
      "registryUrls": [
        "$ACR_URL"
      ]
    }
  ]
}


Working Renovate Configuration
Example .gitlab-ci.yml
image: renovate/renovate:37.382

stages:
  - renovate

variables:
  RENOVATE_BASE_DIR: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/renovate
  RENOVATE_ENDPOINT: $CI_API_V4_URL
  RENOVATE_EXTRA_FLAGS: --autodiscover=true
  RENOVATE_HOST_RULES: | 
    [
      {
        "matchHost": "github.com", 
        "token": "$GITHUB_TOKEN"
      },
      {
        "matchHost": "gitlab.<ENDPOINT>.com", 
        "token": "$GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN", 
        "authType": "Bearer"
      },
      {
        "matchHost": "$ACR_URL", 
        "password": "$ACR_TOKEN", 
        "username": "$ACR_USER"
      }
    ]
  RENOVATE_ONBOARDING: "true"
  RENOVATE_OPTIMIZE_FOR_DISABLED: "true"
  RENOVATE_PLATFORM: gitlab
  RENOVATE_REPOSITORY_CACHE: "true"
  LOG_LEVEL: debug

.matrix:
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - RENOVATE_AUTODISCOVER_FILTER: /<PARENT>/<SUBGROUPA>/.*/
      - RENOVATE_AUTODISCOVER_FILTER: /<PARENT>/<SUBGROUPB>/<PROJECT>/

cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}-renovate
  paths:
    - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/renovate

run_renovate:
  stage: renovate
  resource_group: production
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"'
  script:
    - renovate $RENOVATE_EXTRA_FLAGS
  extends: .matrix

renovate:
  stage: renovate
  script:
    - renovate --dry-run $RENOVATE_EXTRA_FLAGS
  extends: .matrix

With example renovate.json:
{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "extends": [
    "config:recommended"
  ],
  "baseBranches": [
    "main"
  ],
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "groupName": "all non-major dependencies",
      "matchPackagePatterns": [
        "*"
      ],
      "matchUpdateTypes": [
        "minor",
        "patch"
      ]
    },
    {
      "groupName": "all major dependencies",
      "matchPackagePatterns": [
        "*"
      ],
      "matchUpdateTypes": ["major"]
    }
  ],
  "pre-commit": {
    "enabled": true
  }
}




Can you enable debug logging for Renovate to have more info regarding why it cannot reach the container registry. Naming of the image is not an issue. I'd rather bet on rights to access the container registry.

You are correct. I reconfigured the hostrules in my RenovateBot configuration by adding gitlab and docker hostrules. Now it only fails on the hostrules set in the renovate.json of the to be scanned project on the ACR authorization.
Thanks for your help, will have to figure out how to configure my ACR credentials

Hi @Byang117, Can you confirm where you want to configure ACR credentials, whether it’s in the bot or Gitlab?

I managed to make it work with ACR credential configuration in the renovatebot configuration. Putting it in the renovate.json of a to be scanned gitlab project did not work. But the current setup works fine for me. Just have to put all my registries as hostrules in my renovatebot configuration

@Byang117 It's great to hear that you were able to resolve your issue. Could you please document your solution in an answer? It would provide clarity for those encountering similar technical challenges within the community.

Good point, added my current setup

Good suggestion, done.

Working Renovate Configuration
Example .gitlab-ci.yml
image: renovate/renovate:37.382

stages:
  - renovate

variables:
  RENOVATE_BASE_DIR: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/renovate
  RENOVATE_ENDPOINT: $CI_API_V4_URL
  RENOVATE_EXTRA_FLAGS: --autodiscover=true
  RENOVATE_HOST_RULES: | 
    [
      {
        "matchHost": "github.com", 
        "token": "$GITHUB_TOKEN"
      },
      {
        "matchHost": "gitlab.<ENDPOINT>.com", 
        "token": "$GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN", 
        "authType": "Bearer"
      },
      {
        "matchHost": "$ACR_URL", 
        "password": "$ACR_TOKEN", 
        "username": "$ACR_USER"
      }
    ]
  RENOVATE_ONBOARDING: "true"
  RENOVATE_OPTIMIZE_FOR_DISABLED: "true"
  RENOVATE_PLATFORM: gitlab
  RENOVATE_REPOSITORY_CACHE: "true"
  LOG_LEVEL: debug

.matrix:
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - RENOVATE_AUTODISCOVER_FILTER: /<PARENT>/<SUBGROUPA>/.*/
      - RENOVATE_AUTODISCOVER_FILTER: /<PARENT>/<SUBGROUPB>/<PROJECT>/

cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}-renovate
  paths:
    - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/renovate

run_renovate:
  stage: renovate
  resource_group: production
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"'
  script:
    - renovate $RENOVATE_EXTRA_FLAGS
  extends: .matrix

renovate:
  stage: renovate
  script:
    - renovate --dry-run $RENOVATE_EXTRA_FLAGS
  extends: .matrix

With example renovate.json:
{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "extends": [
    "config:recommended"
  ],
  "baseBranches": [
    "main"
  ],
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "groupName": "all non-major dependencies",
      "matchPackagePatterns": [
        "*"
      ],
      "matchUpdateTypes": [
        "minor",
        "patch"
      ]
    },
    {
      "groupName": "all major dependencies",
      "matchPackagePatterns": [
        "*"
      ],
      "matchUpdateTypes": ["major"]
    }
  ],
  "pre-commit": {
    "enabled": true
  }
}



